# Azure AD integration with Office 365

Tags: azure-active-directory

Hello and thank you for reading.

We have Office 365 users and licenses and have recently moved into Azure. We want to connect these together.

I have created a domain controller but am unsure on how to add our existing domain in.

I have tried Azure AD Connect but it asks for 'AD Domain Services administrator', which we do not have. We have no on-premise AD at all, we want to start fresh in the cloud.

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 license then you will have [Azure Active directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/azure-integration) services by default.
If you don't have any on-premises domain then there is no need for Azure AD connect.
Azure AD connect is used  to sync the users from on-prem AD to Azure AD.
In order to add and register your existing domain in Azure , please follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/domains-manage) (domain controller is not needed)